# Translation for Dutch "tot en met": until and including?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, dates, range-inclusion

In Dutch language we use the expression "*tot en met*" to signify a quantity between two measures **including** the last measure. So, for instance, the following:

*woensdag 22 juni **tot en met** vrijdag 24 juni*

... would mean:

Wednesday the 22nd of June until and including Friday the 24th of June, whereas:

*woensdag 22 juni **tot** vrijdag 24 juni*

... would mean:

Wednesday the 22nd of June until but not including Friday the 24th of June

I'm unsure of what the correct expression would be in English language to imply the former.

Is either *until* or maybe *through* enough perhaps? Or is there some other term which expresses this more correctly?

Comment: *Until* definitely does not work.

Comment: **inclusive** (and/or exclusive) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Up to and including" is the standard phrase.

Comment: I think "up to and including" is standard in the UK; "through" (or "thru"!) in the US. Other English-speaking countries, I don't know.

Comment: @slim: Through is ambiguous - see the disagreement in comments on rintaun's answer.

Comment: I am from the northeast US, and "up to and including" is probably about equally as common as "through" and is often used to resolve ambiguity.

Answer (score 9):

I would simply state "from Wednesday to Friday, inclusive".

Comment: @peter, yes, it's bizarre 6 people up-voted the wrong answer above!

Comment: I have heard my Dutch colleagues say `"to and including"` which sounded a bit formal, and then when I was on holiday in the Netherlands I realised that consciously or otherwise they were translating `"tot en met"`. I'd second the suggestion here that adding "inclusive" is the most natural-sounding way to do this in English.

Comment: "... inclusive" would be common usage among people with a maths/science/technology background, and those around them, but is probably not as common elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

To imply the former, I would use "Wednesday the 22nd of June **through** Friday the 24th of June."

Comment: Yes 22 **nd** of course... silly me. :) So **through** is not ambiguous, in that it could imply both meanings?

Comment: @fireeyedboy That's correct. It can only include the 24th, as far as I am aware.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: I disagree. _"Through"_ does not require inclusivity, though circumstances may imply it.  English is in general ambiguous about whether measures are inclusive or exclusive, and _"through"_ isn't an exception to that.  Some explicit phrase like those in the other answers is needed.

Comment: This answer is wrong (no offense).  Wednesday through Friday can certainly mean exclusive.  It's strange it got 6 votes!

Comment: @Joe @Rhodri Can you give me some examples? I'm legitimately at a loss trying to think of any examples where "through" is exclusive.

Comment: Well quite simply, you could say "9th through 19th exclusive," meaning it is exclusive.  You would say "inclusive" to mean it's inclusive.  **through** (or almost any other word) can be used with both specifications, either inclusive or exclusive.  Any legal contract (for example) would certainly specify inclusive or exclusive.  the **actual translation** of tot en met is "up to and including" as Marcin says.  This answer is **utterly, totally, completely wrong**, I'm sorry!  The six people who ticked it up are simply incorrect.  Look at any legal boilerplate (for example) for proof.

Comment: Here's an everyday example of using "through" with "exclusive".  http://www.hacker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=607&start=45&sid=3cf5bce5e13b57d9c8a1dff2b3647371 "sum of the 1st through 5th (exclusive) natural numbers..."  You can google up any number of examples!

Comment: @rintuan there are **NO** "examples" where "through is inclusive".  I will simply copy and paste what Rhodri already exactly explained...  **"Through" does not require inclusivity. English is ambiguous about whether measures are inclusive or exclusive. "Through" isn't an exception to that.** It's just that simple.

Comment: @Joe I cannot agree based on your examples. "Through" is, in normal speech, inclusive by default. While specifically adding "exclusive" does allow the listener to understand that the list is exclusive, available data suggests this not standard usage. If it were, a [Google search for "1 through 10 exclusive"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%221+through+10+exclusive%22) would return more than two real results. There are many more examples of "1 through 10 inclusive", but that number doesn't compare to simply "1 through 10" (which, when actually read, almost universally imply inclusivity).

Comment: @Everyone: The very fact that you are having this discussion illustrates that "through" is ambiguous as to whether it is inclusive.

Comment: I think "through" in this context is also rather American-sounding -- I don't think I've ever heard a UK-English speaker use it.

Comment: Of course "through" is inclusive. If a native speaker said this to another native speaker, inculsivity of the last date would be deduced. Through is through, not before, not after. "to and including", "inclusive"....balderdash.

Comment: "Monday until Friday" is maybe ambiguous, "Monday through Friday" is unambiguously inclusive. If you saw a store advertising "Monday through Saturday" opening hours, would anyone actually expect them to not be open on Saturday?

Comment: -1 - because "through" doesn't necessarily signal "inclusive" to everyone.

Comment: Using the word through, does seem strange to me. If you go through something, it normally means that you go all of the way through and come out at the other end. But, "Wednesday through Friday" sounds unclear because, it does not say what the other end is. Saturday? Or, any of the following days?

Comment: Using through, seems strange because it does not involve saying what the other end is and therefore seems to be an unfinished sentence. Like saying "my bad". (your bad what?).

Answer (score 0):

"through" is an American usage. As an Englishman, I'd say "From Wednesday the 22nd of June to Friday the 24th of June, inclusive"

Comment: You're right. Saying "through" in that context, seems odd and jarring to me.

Comment: Even for an American...you have to check. Just because the word is *supposed* to mean "including" doesn't mean the speaker and all the listeners realize that. Its a subtle nuance, and not every one of us Americans is great with understanding subtle nuance. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For the sentence "Wednesday the 22nd of June until and including Friday the 24th of June"; you can say "Wednesday the 22nd of June until Friday the 24th of June" or, "Wednesday the 22nd of June to Friday the 24th of June".

To use the word "through" instead of until or to, is a feature of American English. You can use it if speaking American English, otherwise it's not necessary and the words until or to will be sufficient and more appropriate.

Comment: Are you saying "from Wednesday until Friday" always includes Friday in the U.K.? It is certainly ambiguous in the U.S.

Comment: In my experience, yes. That's a common way to word such a sentence.

Comment: In the U.S., "I'll be away until Saturday" means I'm returning on Saturday, and "I'll be away through Saturday" means I'm returning on Sunday or later (or possibly Saturday night). What does "I'll be away until Saturday" mean in England?

Comment: The same. It means returning on Saturday.

Answer (score -3):

To avoid the problem it might even be better to say "Wednesday the 22nd of June until Saturday the 25th of June" meaning that Friday the 24th is included but Saturday isn't.

Comment: Many people will assume Saturday is included if you say "until Saturday", so this may not get the intended meaning across.