# until, up to ambiguity — < vs <=

Tags: single-word-requests, ambiguity, range-inclusion

So this is about (preventing) an off-by-one error in the (interpretation of) English language. I have found some similar (**not duplicate**) questions but I don't feel entirely comfortable yet. For context, I'm an application developer, and I want my application to be crystal clear. To that end, I've found existing answers to be unsatisfactory.

Let me give an example sentence that should explain it all.

> The contract lasts from 1 January to 31 January.

The word *to* is ambiguous, although in this case is easily understood to be up to *and including* the 31st. However, it will not always be this easy! In Dutch, we have a simple solution to this ambiguity:

- het contract duurt van 1 januari **tot** 1 februari (<)
- het contract duurt van 1 januari **t/m** 31 januari (<=)

I want to be able to use both forms in my application, but, again, it needs to be crystal clear to the user which of the 2 is meant.

The English equivalent for `t/m` that first comes to mind is `up to and including`. However, that is just too long for my tastes compared to `t/m`. In Dutch, because it's so short, the ambiguity of `tot` is almost non-existent because laziness is not an excuse to write `tot` instead of `t/m`. I fear that some developers will write `up to` or `until` where they actually meant `up to and including`.

I also considered the word `through`, so it would be this:

- The contract lasts from 1 January to 1 February. (<)
- The contract lasts from 1 January through 31 January. (<=)

Is `through` really understood by everyone to be `up to and including`? Or is there an alternative, better word? Or perhaps I'm looking in the wrong direction for a solution and there's a word for `to` that explicitly *excludes* the boundary?

---

**So again, to summarize, I'm looking for:**

- a word or phrase that *unambiguously* means *less than*
- a word or phrase that *unambiguously* means *less than or equals*

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks, but I'm not quite sure what your suggestion is. Use `until before`? I found this question and the answers too vague, and that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translation for Dutch "tot en met": until and including?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30927/translation-for-dutch-tot-en-met-until-and-including)

Comment: @StuartF Thanks. That question has some nice remarks. But it has to be said that the accepted answer is most definitely *not* an answer to my question. There's a comment on the question, and the second answer have led me to a complete answer though.

Comment: Funny that even though I've replied to being marked duplicate, my question was still closed. I feel that my question is broader than simply a translation of `t/m`. And one of the 2 "duplicates" is nothing like my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to StuartF for pointing me to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/30927/137783). Though the accepted answer is useless i.r.t this question, there are some remarks that proved quite valuable. Thanks to Fattie for that. I've settled on the following:

- The contract lasts from 1 January to 1 February ***exclusive***. (<)
- The contract lasts from 1 January to 31 January ***inclusive***. (<=)

These are *both* explicit, and, though longer still than `tot` and `t/m`, are by far not as long as `up to and including`.

Comment: Be careful about inadvertently excluding the start date, not just the end.

Comment: @Lawrence Is that even an issue in English?

Comment: Yes, _exclusive_ can mean “excluding both ends”.

Comment: @Lawrence tbh I see no reason why someone would interpret it that way. The parsing is `from 1 January (to 1 February exclusive)`